# Convert List<String> to List<Integer> for only valid Integer

Tags: java, regex, java-stream

I am trying to convert a `List<String>` to `List<Integer>` by using **Java 8** streams. However, there are a few *invalid integers* in the `List<String>`. How to extract the integer values only and then convert the `String` list to `Integer` list?

For example:

```
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    List<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    String str[] = {"464 mm", "80 mm", "1000", "1220", "48 mm", "1020"};
    strList = Arrays.asList(str);
    intList.addAll(strList.stream().map(Integer::valueOf).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

I am getting error `java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "464 mm"`.

Is there a way, I can use regex

str.replaceAll("[^\d]", " ").trim()

to extract the numbers and then convert. I dont want to use a for loop or while loop as this may hamper my code performance.

Comment: _I dont want to use a for loop or while loop as this may hamper my code performance._ The stream still has to iterate over the list.

Comment: Don’t use this legacy syntax `String str[] =…` You are declaring a variable `str` of type `String[]`, so follow the idiomatic *Type variableName* syntax: `String[] str = …` Further, you don’t need to repeat the type arguments when instantiating a generic class, just use `List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<>(); List<String> strList = new ArrayList<>();` Another note, you can stream over an array using `Arrays.stream(str)`, you don’t need to wrap the array into a `List`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to remove all **non-numeric characters** from each string, you need to apply `map()` before converting the stream of `String` into stream of `Integer`.

```
List<Integer> nums =
     strList.stream()
            .map(s -> s.replaceAll("[^\\d]", ""))
            .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(nums);
```

**Output** for input {"464 mm", "80 mm", "1000", "1220", "48 mm", "1020"}

```
[464, 80, 1000, 1220, 48, 1020]
```

**Note:**

- `trim()` after `replaceAll()` is redundant.
- Since you are adding all the contents of the list generated by the stream pipeline into another list, you might substitute `collect(Collectors.toList())` with `toList()` which is accessible with **Java 16** onwards. The difference is that `toList()` returns an *unmodifiable list* and it more performant than *collector*.
- Iterative solutions almost always **perform better** than stream-based. Lambdas and streams were introduced in Java to provide a way of organizing the code that more readable and concise.